# How can I center my image in white space?

Tags: php, css, image, html

How can I center my image in white space?

I am using HTML, PHP or CSS.  I am not sure of the best approach, but that is what I have involved so far.

I only saw how to align an image within text on `w3schools.com`.  My other attempts, such as:

```
#image {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

only make the image disappear.

Comment: Right or wrong, I use a div tag with text-align: center; in the CSS. There may be a better way of course. I am interested in the answer. I would like to do something different. But this may get you by for now.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar gotcha. was unsure. i did read the rules for this forum, but i did not see whether or not this was an acceptable quesiton.  now i know.  thanks!

Comment: Are u sure the parent container of the image has a width and u need to specify `display : block` on your image. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n16m2axa/)

Comment: PHP has likely to play little role in this — it is a server side language that generates HTML that is sent to the client, so all you need to be concerned with is the markup (HTML) and the styling (CSS). Also, an obligatory link and word of caution when using W3Schools: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I went with @closetnoc solution. Maybe not pretty, but I get the result I was after.

Comment: Good luck with your site! It looks like there are some answers here I will experiment with. If I find something better, I will provide that solution. I just happen to be working on a new responsive design template for my site and updating some/most of the images. My site just looks terrible- but then again, I have never been known for pretty sites, but sites that work well and perform well in search. This is a start! Oddly, I am a photographer, I draw extremely well, I do woodwork, some interior decorating, and I can sculpt. You would think I could make a site somewhat pretty! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`<img>` is not block level tag (its inline level tag ) . So you have two choices in css . one is Using : `display:inline-block` and then giving `margin : 0 auto` , which is used when you are adding more than one image in a line .

second is do the same about `margin` but this time , use `display:block;` ;

I wish this could help .

Comment: Can you give an example of using `display:inline-block` and `margin : 0 auto`?

Comment: @w3d :

For HTML :
    `<img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg">`
For CSS :
    `img {width:200px;height:200px; display:inline-block; margin:0 auto; }`

This results two 200X200 Images , exactly center of a page (horizontally) . What You should know about above code is :

If Images with are more than width of the whole page together , they wont be side by side ! that's why I used width:200px;height:200px; as an example .

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to horizontally center an image (or any element) in CSS is:

```
img {margin:0 auto;)
```

This is the short version of:

```
img (margin:0 auto 0 auto;}
```

which, in turn, is shorthand for:

```
img {margin-top:0; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:auto;}
```

## =====

If the standard method above does not work (perhaps because of conflicting CSS elsewhere in the stylesheet?), there is an alternative way to horizontally center an image (or any element) in CSS IF you know the width of the element.

Assuming the width of the `<img>` is 100px:

```
img {position:relative; left:50%; margin-left:-50px;}
```

It works because:

1) with `margin-left:-50px;` you are telling the browser to consider the left-hand margin of the element as being exactly in the middle of the 100px-width element

2) with left:50%; you are telling the browser to position the left-hand margin of the element exactly in the middle of the element's parent

And so, of course, when you place the middle of the element in the middle of the element's parent, you have succeeded in horizontally centering the element.

## =====

If you are styling for contemporary browsers, you can use the **Flexible Box Layout module** from **CSS3**:

```
img {display:flex; justify-content:center;}
```

Answer (score -1):

### first way

set margins to *50%* on both sites

```
#image {
   margin-left: 50%;
   margin-right: 50%;
}
```

this should center your html-object.

### second way

sometimes this doesn't work for me, so i use the deprecated tag `<center>`.

```
<center>
   <img src="/img.png" alt="blubb">
</center>
```

Comment: center tag is deprecated... Also the `margin : 0 auto;` of OP should sufice for centering

Comment: "sometimes this [set margins to 50%] doesn't work" - it won't work on inline images (the default), they need to be made `block`. And using the `<center>` tag really should not be encouraged! (At least text-align:center will keep it in the CSS.)

Answer (score -2):

< div style="margin:0 auto" >
....image...
< /div >

If you want it center of the page add width:100%

Comment: This won't center "it" at all. There are a few fundamental things wrong with the example posted: 1. The OP wants to center the inner `img`, not the outer container (margins are not inherited, but even if they were, it wouldn't work). 2. You can't center an element which is already full width (so setting `width:100%` is not going to help).